# C++: How do I count the number of nodes in a binary tree for which its value module its height is minor to 2?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, nodes

I'm trying to implement a function which counts the nodes in a binary tree that respect the following condition: ( node->value % height )<2
I know it must be a recursive function and I tried to implement it as it follows:

```
    int count(Node* tree, int h=1){
       if (!tree) return 0;

       if ((tree->value%h)<2)
          return count(tree->left, h++) + count(tree->right, h++) + 1;
       else
          return count(tree->left, h++) + count(tree->right, h++);
    }
```

This function doesn't work and I can't understand where my mistake is. I'll appreciate any help you can give me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the statement

```
return count(tree->left, h++) + count(tree->right, h++) + 1;
```

you are incrementing `h`, which means that one of the calls to count might go with a higher value than the other one. Actually it is undefined behaviour, since the order of evaluation of the two `h++` is not defined.

Write...

```
return count(tree->left, h+1) + count(tree->right, h+1) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Such a call

```
count(tree->left, h++) + count(tree->right, h++)
                  ^^^                       ^^^
```

has undefined behavior.

The function can be defined the following way

```
size_t count( const Node *tree, size_t h = 0 )
{
    return tree == nullptr ? 0
                           : ( ++h, ( tree->value % h < 2 ) +
                                    count( tree->left, h ) + count( tree->right, h ) );
}
```